# Query to find id missing from an item that otherwise uses at least one id from the same group

Tags: mysql, subquery, correlated-subquery

I am trying to come up with a query that shows me which "feeds" make only partial use of a "rule group" by returning a list of rules that are "missing" from a given feed that otherwise uses at least one rule from that group. Here is a simplified example:

Table A has a list of unique rule ids and the rule groups they belong to.

| rulegroup | rule_id |
| --- | --- |
| 450 | 3001 |
| 450 | 3002 |
| 450 | 3003 |
| 450 | 3011 |
| 573 | 7302 |
| 573 | 7303 |
| 573 | 7309 |
| 882 | 8145 |
| 882 | 8146 |
| 882 | 8148 |
| 882 | 8150 |
| 882 | 8151 |

Table B shows which rule ids are used by which feeds.
Some of the rule_id belong to a group above, and others don't.

| feed | rule_id |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1112 |
| A | 7302 |
| A | 7303 |
| A | 7309 |
| A | 4500 |
| A | 7992 |
| B | 7309 |
| B | 8146 |
| B | 8148 |
| B | 8150 |
| B | 7992 |
| C | 1112 |
| C | 4500 |
| C | 9930 |
| D | 3002 |
| D | 1800 |
| D | 2704 |
| D | 9055 |

What I want to find is only feeds that use at least one rule but not all the rules from any given group, along with the group id and the id of the rule that is missing from that feed. For this example, the results table should be:

| feed | rulegroup | rule_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| B | 882 | 8145 |
| B | 882 | 8151 |
| D | 450 | 3001 |
| D | 450 | 3003 |
| D | 450 | 3011 |

i.e.

- Feed A gets no results because it has ALL the rules from group 573.
- Feed B has 3 rules from group 882 but is missing 2 others from that group, so those 2 should appear in the results.
- Feed C has no rules from any group, so it gets no results.
- Feed D has one rule from group 450 but is missing 3 others from that group, so those 3 should appear in the results.

I have been fiddling with something like this:

```
SELECT B.feed, A.rulegroup, A.rule_id
FROM TableA AS A
JOIN TableB AS B ON A.rule_id = B.rule_id
GROUP BY B.feed, A.rulegroup
HAVING COUNT(B.rule_id) < (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TableA WHERE rulegroup = A.rulegroup) AS total
LEFT JOIN TableA AS C ON A.rulegroup = C.rulegroup AND A.rule_id = C.rule_id
```

I either get no results or I get "Every derived table must have its own alias". In real life, however, Tables A and B are each produced by queries with about 8 joins each, so it's complicating my thinking about this and it's possible that I've just made mistakes. Perhaps if I can confirm what works for the simpler example above, I'll be able to translate that to my more complex work use case. Can someone give me a query that would work for the above? Bonus points if you can accomplish this without using a correlated subquery.

Edited to add: I pasted an earlier attempted code above that mistakenly has a join after the HAVING clause, but I have also tried this arrangement:

```
FROM TableA AS A
JOIN TableB AS B ON A.rule_id = B.rule_id
LEFT JOIN TableA AS C ON A.rulegroup = C.rulegroup AND A.rule_id = C.rule_id
GROUP BY B.feed, A.rulegroup
HAVING COUNT(B.rule_id) < (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TableA WHERE rulegroup = A.rulegroup)
```

Comment: You can't have `LEFT JOIN` after `HAVING`. All joins come at the beginning. You should be getting a syntax error.